# Version 23 permission checking

Tags: android, permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow, user-permissions

I'm asking for permission to use maps with this code . . .

```
    permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
    if (!(permissionCheck == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED))
    {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
        new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                PERMISSION_TO_USE_LOCATIONMANAGER);
    }
```

That works ok but my problem is that there are 19 places in my app where I reference map related objects and the compiler flags every one of them.  The way I am addressing this issue is to wrap each and every reference in similar code ...

```
   public void onPause() {

        permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        if (permissionCheck == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            PSLocManager.removeUpdates(PSLocListener);
        }
    super.onPause();

    }
```

This all works ok but is it necessary to do this in this way?  It's a lot of code.
Thanks,
Dean

Comment: In some cases, yes. For example, `onPause()` will be called when you do not yet have the permission, since it will be called when the permission dialog-themed activity takes over the foreground. In other cases, where you're quite certain that you have the permission before that code could get called, there should be a quick-fix to suppress the Lint check, IIRC.

Comment: @DeanBlakely Building on Mark's comment, the annotation to suppress the compiler whining is `@SuppressWarnings("MissingPermission")`